# Координаты конца выделения в textarea

Tags: javascript

Как получить координаты конца выделения (clientX, clientY) в textarea при программной установке диапазона выделения?

Когда текст выделяется мышью, там все понятно - слушаем событие mouseup, а что делать, когда выделяется методом `setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd)`?

Рабочий пример - десктопная версия Яндекс Браузера. В нём иконка вызова контекстного меню (позволяет вызывать меню левой кнопкой) появляется в конце выделения не только при выделении мышью, но и при выделении `setSelectionRange()`